# Выборка по нескольким значениям в связанных таблицах

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, select

Есть 2 таблицы.
Таблица ad — товары,  ad_caregory — Свойства товаров.
Таблица ad_caregory связана через category_id с таблицей ad (поле id).
У одного товара может быть много свойств.  Задача: выбрать все товары, которые отвечают заданным свойствам.
Сделал выборку по 1 свойству, а при использовании перечисления — получаю нулевой результат. Что делаю не так?

```
    SELECT
    tov.id AS id_tov,
    tov.title AS title_tov,
    cat.category_id AS category_cat,
    cat.ad_id AS ad_cat
FROM
    `ad` AS tov,
    `ad_caregory` AS cat
WHERE
    cat.ad_id = tov.id AND
    cat.category_id = '1' AND
    cat.category_id = '5'
ORDER BY
    tov.`id`
```

Comment: изменил запрос, но выводятся все значения, которым соответствует хотя бы 1 из запрашиваемых свойств, а нужно что бы выводились значения, которые соответствуют только запрошенным свойствам. SELECT
    tov.id AS id_tov,
    tov.title AS title_tov,
    cat.category_id AS category_cat,
    cat.ad_id AS ad_cat
FROM
    `ad` AS tov,
    `ad_caregory` AS cat
WHERE
    cat.ad_id = tov.id AND
    cat.category_id IN (1,5)
ORDER BY
    tov.`id`

Answer (score 1):

Решил следующим образом:

```
SELECT
    tov.id AS id_tov,
    tov.title AS title_tov,
    cat.category_id AS category_cat,
    cat.ad_id AS ad_cat
FROM
    ad AS tov,
    ad_caregory AS cat
WHERE
    cat.ad_id = tov.id AND cat.category_id IN(1,3,9)
GROUP BY
    tov.id
HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 3)
```

где, IN(1,3,9) - идентификаторы свойств, а в HAVING  (COUNT(*) = 3) указываем их количество.